# Mutation Observers: detecting visibility changes inherited from a parent element

Tags: javascript, html, css, onchange, mutation-observers

I am trying to detect when a target element becomes visible (visible or display:block) regardless of where it is placed in the HTML.

I tried using MutationObservers, however, the visibility change can only be detected if the observed element has a direct change in CSS properties. Thus, it ignores changes to its parent element.

```
var targetNode = document.getElementById('target');
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(){
    alert(targetNode.offsetWidth);
    }
);
observer.observe(targetNode,  { attributes: true, childList: true });
```

The PROBLEM occurs when a parent element CSS properties are changed and it is not detected/observed by the MuatationObserver attached to the child/target element as seen in in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jb38Lran/15/). Is there a way (aside from using Intervals) for the observed DOM element to detect changes in CSS that is inherited from parents?

Comment: You can use `IntersectionObserver` instead.

Comment: Yes this seems to be what I need. The browser compatibility doesn't seem optimal though.

Comment: Did you find the solution to this? I had similar problem

Answer (score -2):

You can observe the parent and the child:

```
observer.observe(targetNode, options);
observer.observe(parentNode,  options);
```

```js
var targetNode = document.getElementById('target');
var parentNode = document.getElementById('parent');
var observer = new MutationObserver(function (changes) { // or replace changes by just:  [ { target } ]
  const target = changes[0].target
 if (target === parentNode)
   alert('parent')

 if (target === targetNode)
   alert('target')

 console.log(target)
});

var options = { 
 attributes: true, 
  childList: true, 
  attributeFilter: ['style', 'class'] 
}

observer.observe(targetNode, options);
observer.observe(parentNode,  options);
```

```html
<script>
function showParent() {
    document.getElementById("parent").style.display = "block";
}
function showChild() {
    document.getElementById("target").style.display = "block";
}
</script>

<button onclick="showParent()">showParent</button>
<button onclick="showChild()">showChild</button>
<div id="parent" style="display:none;"> 
  parent
  <div id="target" style="display:none;">target</div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Well like I said I have to be able to observe a target element regardless where it is in the HTML. Thus, I don't have the luxury of knowing which of the ancestors needs to observed.