# Running a JavaScript function when a DOM object becomes exposed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

I am working on replacing a button in some 3rd party software.  The button is initially hidden in an accordion menu. I want to target the `div` holding this button and set the `innerHTML` with my own button.

My issue is that since the button is initially hidden I am unsure how to target it.

I run:

```
    const buttonList = document.getElementsByClassName(
        "sendbird-channel-settings-accordion__footer"
    );
```

Which initially is just an empty list. And then I want to run the following to replace the existing button:

```
        if (buttonList.length) {
            console.log(buttonList, "test");
            buttonList[0].innerHTML = `
        <button
            style={{
                display: "inline-block",
                boxShadow: "none",
                borderRadius: "4px",
                padding: "0px",
                fontFamily: "'Roboto', sans-serif",
                fontFamily:
                    "var(--sendbird-font-family-default)",
                cursor: "pointer",
            }}
            onClick={setShouldShowCreateChatModal(true)}
        >
            Item Test
        </button>`;
        }
```

My code works expect I don't know how to get it to run as soon as the desired class becomes available.

I don't have access to the accordion menu either as that is part of the third party software.

Comment: By hidden you mean "not rendered"? You could use the [Mutation Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to respond to changes in HTML. The solution will be hacky, though.

Comment: I believe not rendered is correct.

Comment: You could try adding an event handler to the accordion's open event (whatever that may be), and running your code in there.

Comment: @imvain2 can I do this without access to the accordion?  The accordion is part of the third party software and I don't have access to any of its onClick functions.

Comment: @TrevorDammon, with event handlers you can actually create your own event handler and it will be ran either before or after the original (depending on what one is called first). So you just need to right click on the parent and try creating an event handler based maybe initially on the parent object.

Comment: Be careful with the string you're setting as the `innerHTML`: it contains JSX syntax which the browser will not be able to parse.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to understand the exact question asked. If you want to add a listener for if the element becomes visible, you can go down that rabbit hole [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52427337/mutation-observers-detecting-visibility-changes-inherited-from-a-parent-element).

If you simply want to check if the item is loaded onscreen, you can use the following script:

```js
const button = document.getElementById('button')
button.addEventListener('load', load())
function load(){
    console.log('the button was loaded')
}
```

```html
<button id='button'>Button</button>
```

Comment: I think I want to check if the item is loaded onscreen, however the code you provided does not rerun with every DOM change. The first line of your code returns an empty array initially. Then when I perform the actions to load the item to the DOM the code does not rerun immediately.